# Regex to check text validity

Tags: regex

I need to do some data filtering and I have a question here.
How can I check if text is formatted like this:

> TEXT-1/1

.
TEXT - some text in capital letters, 1 - any positive integer.
So, for example, "FA-5/9" will be valid but "FA-AV" will be invalid.

Thanks for answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one will match what you want:

`[A-Z]+-\d\/\d`

Explained:

`[A-Z]+` # will match one or more A-Z characters [(link)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

`-`   # will match dash (-)

`\d\/\d` # will match digit slash digit (1/1)